# Can I pass a value to an optional parameter to indicate I want the parameter to be set to default?

Tags: c#

I have a couple of external functions, one has an enum with a list of colours which do not correspond to `System.Drawing.Color`, this enum also provides "default" as one of its options.

I have a second external function which takes a lot of arguments, one being an optional `System.Drawing.Color`. If this is not provided, it uses the next colour in its internal list, which I don't have access to.

At the moment I'm doing an if statement, if default then I just pass nothing, else pass a helper functions output. It looks something like:

```
if (extEnum == LimitedColor.Default){
    extFunction();
} else {
    extFunction(GetColor(extEnum));
}
```

Where `GetColor` is a simple switch statement to translate `LimitedColor` to `System.Drawing.Color`.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this inline?

I was hoping that the `default` keyword would do this, but it seems to only be useful in generating the default initialised value of a given class as per [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default) - unless I have misunderstood this completely.

Comment: Do you have access to `extFunction`'s source code? Does `extFunction(Color ...)` have sanitization behaviours when it receives `null` (not sure if `Color` can be null) or `Color.Empty`? If there are, maybe you can work around that; if not, I think @Chuck's answer below is good. Wrap these conversions into a function and then use that function only.

Comment: Go look at the optional param of extFunction and see what it defaults to, and return that from GetColor when LimitedColor.Default?

Comment: @dugas It defaults to the next `Color` in a `Private` scoped list. I don't have access to the list, nor the pointer indicating what the next value should be.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang `Color` is non nullable, and the external library does not handle a case where it is. Besides that, in this case, it is not `Color?`, so a compile time error is generated if I try. `Color.Empty` is treated as `Color.Transparent`, so no luck there either :(

Comment: I never had such an idea, but I found [Type.Missing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.missing), you can try it

Comment: "It defaults to the next Color in a Private scoped list" - I wonder how this is implemented The [default value of a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) can only be a constant exprssion, `new ValuieType()` or `default(ValueType)`. There is no way to reference an internal list here. Are you really sure it is implemented this way? Or are these rather two overloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've only got a couple external functions then I'd stick them in a wrapper class and only call that class' methods. Then the wrapper runs your if statement/conversion for you.

:EDIT:

I'm not on my phone, so now I can give you a bit more of an exhaustive answer.

C# doesn't have free functions, so it's not really possible to just have `extFunction()`. If you've got a function it's either a member function, and then you could just modify the signature, or it's a part of some other class.

If it's part of some other class, then you could write an extension method to wrap just the method, but this is essentially still just a wrapper class.

Extension methods are static methods that use the `this` keyword with the first argument. They've been really transformative for me so I'm a huge fan. I'm assuming you've actually got some external class, `ExtClass`, and you're creating an instance of that external class, like:

```
ExtClass extInstance = new ExtClass();
```

Then in your code you're calling:

```
extInstance.extFunction();
```

You could put this in a script called `ExtClassExtensionMethods` and do what you want there. Here's all the example code I've written about how I'm imagining your scenario:

Sounds like you've got a class you can't access:

```
public class ExtClass // I'm assuming you can't access this
{
    public void extFunction()
    {
        // Stuff with no color
    }

    public void extFunction(Color color)
    {
        // Stuff with color
    }
}
```

You have some enum `LimitedColor`:

```
public enum LimitedColor
{
    Default,
    Red,
    White,
    Blue
}
```

You have a function `GetColor` but it looks like a member function. I'd make it a `Helper` function so anything can access it. I use `public static partial class Helpers` and split my Helpers files based on what they do. For this, I think the following is sufficient:

```
public static partial class Helpers
{
    public static Color GetColor(LimitedColor limitedColor)
    {
        switch (limitedColor)
        {
            case LimitedColor.Blue:
                return Color.blue;
            case LimitedColor.Red:
                return Color.red;
            case LimitedColor.White:
                return Color.white;
            default:
                return Color.black;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'd write the extension method to wrap the method:

```
public static class TransformListExtensionMethods
{
    public static void extFunction(this ExtClass extInstance, LimitedColor limitedColor)
    {
        if (limitedColor == LimitedColor.Default)
        {
            extInstance.extFunction();
        }
        else
        {
            extInstance.extFunction(Helpers.GetColor(limitedColor));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here you can see how it's used:

```
public class ListUser
{
    public ExtClass extInstance = new ExtClass();

    public void Stuff()
    {
        Color color = Color.red;
        LimitedColor limitedColor = LimitedColor.Default;
        
        extInstance.extFunction(); // Valid!
        extInstance.extFunction(color); // Also valid!
        extInstance.extFunction(limitedColor); // Also valid!
    }
}
```

---

As a little post-script here, I'll give you the totally excellent tip I was given once - you can write extension methods for enums! So, instead of having `partial static partial class Helpers` and then doing all that work to then call `Helpers.GetColor(limitedColor)`, you can make an extension method that implements that factory-getter style and **then you can just call `limitedColor.GetColor()`.**

```
public static class LimitedColorExtensionMethods
{
    public static Color GetColor(this LimitedColor limitedColor)
    {
        switch (limitedColor)
        {
            case LimitedColor.Blue:
                return Color.blue;
            case LimitedColor.Red:
                return Color.red;
            case LimitedColor.White:
                return Color.white;
            default:
                return Color.black;
        }
    }
}
```

And again once you implement this you can just do:

```
extInstance.extFunction(limitedColor.GetColor());
```

Comment: That would be best practice if this was considerably reused, but as this is the only place I'm calling this currently, a helper function would not abstract the problem meaningfully.

Comment: If this is the case, imo I think the `if` approach in OP is the one I'd use. Unless there're still some hidden C# voodoo magic out there, OP's and @Chuck's solutions are the ones I'd consider.

Comment: @AndrewWynn What are you after then? Some kind of ternary-like statement?

Comment: Well, that's a considerable reply, thanks for your effort. I think I'm going to implement the extension method for the enum, and I will take your advice in future implementations which repeatedly call these external functions, but on this occasion I'm calling 6 different functions which would all need to be extended, and I'm only using each one once (well twice for the color/nocolor)

Comment: @AndrewWynn there's a [famous xkcd comic about automating stuff](https://xkcd.com/1319/). I agree some kind of a ternary-like operation that causes the argument to "evaporate" would be nice, but you've got to remember that the compiler has to resolve the function calls, so if there were such a `GetColor()` operator that could return a color or "evaporate," because it's got the possibility to return a `Color` (etc.) then the compiler can't know which overloaded method to call - the one that takes a `Color` or the one that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simpler way to achieve this inline?

Not really. There is no way to explicitly use the default value:

```
// Not possible
extFunction(color: some_special_word_to_say_use_default_value);
```

However, in case

- `extFunction(Color? color = null)` or
- ~`extFunction(Color color = Color.None)`

you could:

```
extFunction(
     color: (extEnum != LimitedColor.Default) ? GetColor(extEnum) : null); // or Color.None
```